# Towards a formula for the Euler $\phi$ function?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

1. $\Phi_n(1)$ and $\Phi_n(-1)$ for the cyclotomic polynomials are well-known.

   I am now looking for
   $$\Phi_n(i)$$ and/or $$\Phi_n(-i)$$ with $i$ the complex unit.
2. The reason is :

   I suppose it is true that $(1-i)^{\phi(n)}\Phi_n(i)$ is either zero or of the form
   $$(-1)^{f(n)}2^{g(n)}$$ for some rational valued functions. 
   Just now $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are unknown to me. But if all calculations would succeed
   by taking logarithms $\phi(n)$ may perhaps be calculated.

   The ideas behind that rely on the polynomials defined by William E Heierman published   on his Web Site.

Comment: $\Phi_{28}(i)=7.$ Moreover, $\Phi_{4p}(i)=p$.

Comment: I see. I checked and have to note that for $n=12=4\cdot 3$ my above assumption is wrong as I get the value$$-12=(-1)^12^23$$contrary to the formula given.

Comment: At least your formulas below show that $\Phi_{12}(i)=3$ and so the $3$ cancels on both sides and one could try to calculate $\phi(12)$ to check the  result/method.

Comment: I checked. $\phi(12)=4$ and $(1-i)^4=-4$. So both sides agree and one could have solved for $\phi(12)$.

Comment: BTW: the exceptional case $n\equiv 0\mod 4$ is deeply analyzed by Heierman.

Comment: I just got by experiment with CAS for $n=3,5,\cdots,25$ an interesting conjecture about the function $g(n)$ above in the exponent of $2$. It is fairly simple and astonishing that $g(n)=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}+1$ if $n=2^k$ and for all other $n$ it is $g(n)=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$. Just now I have not (yet) a formal proof of this.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180434/looking-for-ways-how-to-calculate-phi-ni

Answer (score 1):

After a long thought, my conjecture is instead the following. Let $\nu=\nu_2(n)$, $\omega_1$ be the number of distinct prime numbers $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ that divide $n$, $\omega_3$ be the number of distinct prime numbers $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ that divide $n$. I claim:
$$\begin{array}{rl}\textbf{If...}&\textbf{then...}\\
n=2&\Phi_n(i)=1+i\\
n=4&\Phi_n(i)=0\\
n=2^{k},k\geq 2&\Phi_n(i)=2\\
n=4p&\Phi_n(i)=p\\
\omega_1\geq 1,n\neq 4p & \Phi_n(i)=1\\
\nu\geq 3&\Phi_n(i)=1\\
\omega_3\geq 3&\Phi_n(i)=1\\
\omega_1=0,\omega_3=1,\nu=0&\Phi_n(i)=i\\
\omega_1=0,\omega_3=1,\nu=1&\Phi_n(i)=-i\\
\omega_1=0,\omega_3=2,\nu<2&\Phi_n(i)=-1\\
\omega_1=0,\omega_3=2,\nu=2&\Phi_n(i)=1.\\
\end{array}$$
Please check this conjecture. I am too lazy now to prove that it holds in virtue of:
$$\Phi_n(i)=\prod_{d\mid n}\left(i^{n/d}-1\right)^{\mu(d)}$$
by an induction depending on eleven different cases, but I can find somewhere the strength to do my math if this is really useful.

Comment: Sorry. What is $\nu=\nu_2(n)$ ?

Comment: The exponent of the greatest power of two that divides $n$.

Comment: Its somewhat hard for me to understand your cases. E.g. $\Phi_{15}(i)$ falls in what category and why ?

Comment: $15$ is divided by $5$, a prime congruent to $1\pmod{4}$, hence falls into the $\omega_1\geq 1,n\neq 4p$ case.

Comment: What about $81$ ? I get $\Phi_{81}(i)=-i$.

Comment: Corrections: (1) The list is missing $\Phi_1(i)=i-1$. (2) The case for $\Phi_n(i)=p$ should have $n=4p^k$, not just $4p$. (3) The case for $\Phi_n(i)=2$ needs $k>2$, and it’s really just a special case of $4p^k$ with $p=2$. (4) The cases for $\Phi_n(i)=\pm i$ are mixed up (this includes the 81 example): if $n=p^k$ where $p\equiv3\pod4$, then $\Phi_n(i)=i$ for $k$ odd, and $\Phi_n(i)=-i$ for $k$ even; if $n=2p^k$, it’s the other way round. (5) The $\Phi_n(i)=1$ cases also need to be fixed, but they are simply the complement of all the other cases.

Comment: I can confirm e.g. your $n=p^k$ calculation for $p\equiv3\mod4$. Some other cases I have to check. But what do you want to say with "but they are simply the complement of all the other cases". I dont understand what "complement" means.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29 . This simply means that all $n$ that do not fall in one of the listed cases where $\Phi_n(i)$ is $0,-1,\pm i,i\pm1,p$ must have $\Phi_n(i)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I made a calculation for $n\ge 3$ and get

$$\prod_{E_n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{\Phi_n(-1)}{2^{\phi(n)}}$$

This formula may be totally wrong at this moment.

I have not the CAS Mathematica available and also not the programming skills to check it by other CAS freely available.

Comment: Maybe I missed a factor of $(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}$ on the right side as the formula is not correct and I dont find the error in my calculation. To calculate $\phi(n)$ by logarithm it would be sufficient to take the absolute value on the left side.

Comment: I suppose that the left side can be somehow calculated or is in correspondance with the Chebychev Polynomial of the 2nd kind. So the calculation of $\phi(n)$ would be possible by evaluation of polynomials.

Comment: Sorry. It is $$E_n=\lbrace k\mid 1\le k\le n\ \&\ (k,n)=1\rbrace$$.

Answer (score 0):

I recalculated the formula and it is indeed

$$\prod_{E_n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}\frac{\Phi_n(-1)}{2^{\phi(n)}}$$

for $n>2$. Taking absolute values on both sides allows one then to calculate $\phi(n)$.

Comment: After rebrooding I think the formula is as funny as useless for calculating $\phi(n$ by computer numerically. Only if one finds another expression for the left-hand side not involving $E_n$ it might make sense.